# Show that the following expression is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

V=$\{p ∈ P_2(\mathbb{R}): p'(1) +$  $\int_0^{\frac 12} p(t)dt=0\}$

Now I know that $p'(1)$ is always zero, because the derivative of a constant is always $0$. Is this interpretation correct? Or do they mean if the derivative of the expression when $p=1$, which may not necessarily be $0$.

I know for subspaces we have to prove existence, closer under addition and scalar multiplication but I have trouble with the setting out.

Also, how do I find a basis for the subspace?

Comment: Forget about showing basis, just show that given $p, f \in V$,  $\alpha p + f$ is in $V$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $0$ is in $V$.

Comment: They mean the derivative of $p(t)$ when $t=1$. So, as you said, this is not automatically $0$. For example, if $p(t)=t^2+3t$, then $p'(2)=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p,q \in V$ and $a \in \mathbb R$, we see that $$p'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 p(t) dt = 0 \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, q'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 q(t) dt = 0$$ but then defining $r(x) = p(x) + aq(x)$ we see that \begin{align*} r'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 r(t) dt &= p'(1) + aq'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 [p(t) + aq(t) ]dt \\ &=\left(p'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 p(t) dt \right)  + a \left( q'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 q(t) dt \right) \\ &= 0 + 0 = 0 \end{align*} Thus $r \in V$. This shows that $V$ is closed under addition and multiplication by scalars. To find a basis, assume that $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ is in $V$. Then $$0 = p'(1) + \int^{1/2}_0 p(t) dt = 2a + b + \frac{a}{24} + \frac b 8 + \frac c 2 = \frac{49}{24}a + \frac 9 8 b + \frac 1 2 c$$ thus $c = -\frac{49}{12}a - \frac{9}{4} b$. Thus we see that $$p(x) = ax^2 + bx -\frac{49}{12}a - \frac 9 4 b = a \left( x^2 - \frac{49}{12} \right) + b \left(x - \frac 9 4 \right).$$ Thus any polynomial in $V$ can be built using $$e_1(x) =  x^2 - \frac{49}{12} \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\,  e_2(x) = x - \frac 9 4. $$
It is also clear that these are linearly independent so these form a basis for $V$.